# Taking SpringBoot Heapdumps & Threaddumps when running on Pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Is there any recommended approach to taking Heapdumps & Threaddumps for a Spring Boot app running in a Pod on AKS?

And how to download the dump afterwards to my desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to take a heapdump and threaddumps. The easiest way for a Spring Boot app should be the Actuator endpoint.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#heapdump